# onMenuItemSelected never executes

Tags: android

When I click on a menu item I am presented with the following message in DDMS:

**Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@43882778**

Here is most of the code from the Main class where the onMenuClick is being ignored.

```
public class Main extends TabActivity {

 public static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 0;

 private static final int ADD_ID = Menu.FIRST;

 private Long listId;
 private DbHelper mDbHelper;
 private Cursor mCursor;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Set the list id
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
         listId = extras.getLong("listId");
        }

        // Open the database
        mDbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        mDbHelper.open();

        // Setup the tabs
        createTabs();
    }

    public void createTabs() {
     mCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllCategories(listId);
     startManagingCursor(mCursor);

     for (int i = 0; i [less than symbol] mCursor.getCount(); i++)
     {
      createTab(
    mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")),
    mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("category")));
     }
    }

    public void createTab(Long categoryId, String category) {
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;

        intent = new Intent();
      intent.putExtra("Test", category);
      intent.setClass(this, Categories.class);
  spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(category);
   spec.setContent(intent);
   spec.setIndicator(category);
  tabHost.addTab(spec);     
    }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  menu.add(0, ADD_ID, 0, R.string.menu_addCategory).setIcon(R.drawable.add_grey);
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case ADD_ID:
   addCategory();
   return true;
  }

  return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
 }

 public void addCategory() {
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setClass(this, CategoryEdit.class);
  startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

  switch (requestCode) {
  case ACTIVITY_CREATE:
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Bundle createExtras = intent.getExtras();
    mDbHelper.addCategory(createExtras.getString("category"));

   }
  }
 }
}
```

Originally my CategoryEdit.class wasn't listed in the AndroidManifest.xml file.  I have added that to the manifest and still receive the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use ::

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
```

instead of::

```
 public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
```

Comment: That was it!  Thank you very much.  I'm not sure what the difference is between onOptionsItemSelected or onMenuItemSelected, but I'm going to do some research and find out.  Thanks again for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to `intent.setClass(TabActivity.this, CategoryEdit.class);`

If that doesn't work I'm gonna need some more output from Logcat, you can one line and it is really helping much.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I tried this, but it didn't solve the problem.  The onOptionsItemSelected suggestion worked.